# What's the best version combination for Drupal 7 and Civi 4.5

Tags: drupal, error

Tried installing drupals starter-kit with civi with errors wouldn't finish. Tried numerous version combinations none would complete. Do you have a combo suggestion?

Comment: can you explain the reasons for wanting civi 4.5 - is this a case of having a d6 + 4.5 system and you are just trying to resolve the d6 -> d7 upgrade without updating civicrm

Answer (score 1):

the stable versions are 4.6.x and 4.7.x, I'm not sure they are kits that install both drupal and civi, but the recommended path is to install drupal first, then follow the instructions to enable civi.

https://civicrm.org/download